# Android extract array of properties of array of objects

Tags: java, android, arrays

I was wondering if there's an effective way to extract an array of properties from an array of custom class objects. For example if I have something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Double p1;
    private String p2;
    private MyProperty p3;

    public MyClass() {}
}
```

and in somewhere I have an ArrayList filled with objects of this class:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<>();
```

and I'd like to get a list of one of the properties:

```
ArrayList<MyProperty> listOfP3 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Double> listOfP1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

All I can think of is iterating through `listOfObjects` and copying the desired properties one by one to a new array... Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT:**
If possible one that works with Java 7 also

Answer (score 4):

Probably the cleanest way to do it is to use Streams. Something like this:

```
List<String> listOfP2= listOfObjects.stream().map(x->x.getP2()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course in MyClass you need to add a getter for those fields.

Comment: Thanks, I really like this solution! However, I'm using Java 7 so the lambda is not supported :( Any possible solution for Java 7, or I should start thinking about updating Java? :D

Comment: Sadly I cant really think of any clean way to do that in Java 7. You will have to iterate over the whole List, extract the property and add it to a new List.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 and higher, you can utilize the `stream` API (as @Amongalen already answered). There is a different possibility of accessing methods: Instead of `x -> x.getP1()` you can just write `MyClass::getP1`:

```
List<Double> p1List = myObjects.stream().map(MyClass::getP1).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> p2List = myObjects.stream().map(MyClass::getP2).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<MyProperty> p3List = myObjects.stream().map(MyClass::getP3).collect(Collectors.toList());
```